# How to increase the speed for SVM classifier using Sk-learn

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

I'm trying to build a spam mail classifier and I've collected multiple datasets from over internet(eg. SpamAssassin Database for spam/ham mails) and built this :

```
import os
import numpy
from pandas import DataFrame
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.cross_validation import KFold
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix, f1_score
from sklearn import svm

NEWLINE = '\n'

HAM = 'ham'
SPAM = 'spam'

SOURCES = [
    ('C:/data/spam', SPAM),
    ('C:/data/easy_ham', HAM),
    # ('C:/data/hard_ham', HAM), Commented out, since they take too long
    # ('C:/data/beck-s', HAM),
    # ('C:/data/farmer-d', HAM),
    # ('C:/data/kaminski-v', HAM),
    # ('C:/data/kitchen-l', HAM),
    # ('C:/data/lokay-m', HAM),
    # ('C:/data/williams-w3', HAM),
    # ('C:/data/BG', SPAM),
    # ('C:/data/GP', SPAM),
    # ('C:/data/SH', SPAM)
]

SKIP_FILES = {'cmds'}


def read_files(path):
    for root, dir_names, file_names in os.walk(path):
        for path in dir_names:
            read_files(os.path.join(root, path))
        for file_name in file_names:
            if file_name not in SKIP_FILES:
                file_path = os.path.join(root, file_name)
                if os.path.isfile(file_path):
                    past_header, lines = False, []
                    f = open(file_path, encoding="latin-1")
                    for line in f:
                        if past_header:
                            lines.append(line)
                        elif line == NEWLINE:
                            past_header = True
                    f.close()
                    content = NEWLINE.join(lines)
                    yield file_path, content


def build_data_frame(path, classification):
    rows = []
    index = []
    for file_name, text in read_files(path):
        rows.append({'text': text, 'class': classification})
        index.append(file_name)

    data_frame = DataFrame(rows, index=index)
    return data_frame


data = DataFrame({'text': [], 'class': []})
for path, classification in SOURCES:
    data = data.append(build_data_frame(path, classification))

data = data.reindex(numpy.random.permutation(data.index))

pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('count_vectorizer', CountVectorizer(ngram_range=(1, 2))),
    ('classifier', svm.SVC(gamma=0.001, C=100))
])

k_fold = KFold(n=len(data), n_folds=6)
scores = []
confusion = numpy.array([[0, 0], [0, 0]])
for train_indices, test_indices in k_fold:
    train_text = data.iloc[train_indices]['text'].values
    train_y = data.iloc[train_indices]['class'].values.astype(str)

    test_text = data.iloc[test_indices]['text'].values
    test_y = data.iloc[test_indices]['class'].values.astype(str)

    pipeline.fit(train_text, train_y)
    predictions = pipeline.predict(test_text)

    confusion += confusion_matrix(test_y, predictions)
    score = f1_score(test_y, predictions, pos_label=SPAM)
    scores.append(score)

print('Total emails classified:', len(data))
print('Support Vector Machine Output : ')
print('Score:' + str((sum(scores) / len(scores))*100) + '%')
print('Confusion matrix:')
print(confusion)
```

The lines which I've commented out are the collection of mails, even if I comment out most of the datasets and select the one with least amount of mails, it still runs extremely slow (~15minutes) and give accuracy of about 91%. How do I improve the speed and accuracy?

Comment: How many documents is it? It looks like the number of documents is rather high for a kernel. Have you considered using Linear SVM?

Comment: @DavidMaust there are about 30k documents in total (including the commented out documents). The number of uncommented documents are about 3k. I'll try LinearSVM now...

Comment: Yes. that is a lot for kernel SVM. Linear SVM will probably be do much better. `svc.SVM(kernel='linear')`

Comment: @DavidMaust Tested on 3k mails, performance has improved slightly and accuracy went up from 91% to 94.5%. Anything else I could add to increase accuracy? Thanks

Comment: Sure. converting this to an answer....

Comment: There are six files in the SA dump which are not email samples, make sure you have removed those! IIRC there is a file named `cmds` in each subdirectory. (Though only three of your dirs look like SA public corpus; the rest looks like Enron or TREC. Mayde add a pointer to where you downloaded these?)

Comment: Also, these corpora are pretty old. For real life use, you want to add fresh spam and ham samples of your own.

Comment: @tripleee thanks, i've already taken care of the cmds files, you can find it in the code `SKIP_FILES = {cmds}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using kernel SVM. There are two problems with this.

**Running Time Complexity of Kernel SVM:** The first step in performing kernel SVM is building a similarity matrix, which becomes the feature set. With 30,000 documents, the number of elements in the similarity matrix becomes 90,000,000. This grows quickly as your corpus grows since the matrix grows the square of the number of documents in your corpus. This problem could be solved using using `RBFSampler` in scikit-learn, but you probably don't want to use that, for the next reason.

**Dimensionality:** You are using term and bigram counts as your feature set. This is an extremely high dimensional dataset. Using an RBF kernel in high dimensional spaces, even small differences (noise) can create a large impact in similarity results. See the [curse of dimensionality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curse_of_dimensionality). This is likely why your RBF kernel yields worse results than a linear kernel.

**Stochastic Gradient Descent:** SGD can be used instead of the standard SVM, and with good parameter tuning it may yield similar or possibly even better results. The drawback is SGD has more parameters to tune regarding the learning rate and learning rate schedule. Also, for few passes SGD is not ideal. In that case other algorithms like Follow The Regularized Leader (FTRL) will do better. Scikit-learn does not implement FTRL though.  Using [SGDClassifier](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.SGDClassifier.html) with `loss="modified_huber"` often works well.

Now that we have the problems out of the way, there are several ways you can improve performance:

**tf-idf weights**: Using [tf-idf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf), more common words are weighted less. This allows the classifier to better represent rare words that are more meaningful. This can be implemented by switching `CountVectorizer` to [TfidfVectorizer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.TfidfVectorizer.html)

**Parameter tuning:** With linear SVM, there is no `gamma` parameter, but the `C` parameter can be used to greatly improve results. In the case of `SGDClassifier`, the alpha and learning rate parameters can be tuned as well.

**ensembling:** Running your model on multiple subsamples and averaging the result will often produce a robust model than a single run. This can be done in scikit-learn using the `BaggingClassifier`. Also combining different approaches can produce significantly better results. If substantially different approaches are used, consider using a stacked model with a tree model (RandomForestClassifier or GradientBoostingClassifier) as the last stage.

Comment: using tf-idf and LinearSVC has boosted the speed and is showing a shocking accuracy of 99.5% :)

Comment: Excellent. That's cross validated accuracy?